# Pascal Segmentation Fault parsing Text File

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I am working on a Question/Answer UI application in Pascal / Lazarus. My problem is that upon invoking below code through a button click, the program crashes with a `Segmentation Fault` error.

```
// more declarations... (UI Form, Buttons, ...)

type
  TQuestion = class(TObject)
    title: string;
    answers: array of string;
    correct: integer;
  end;

var
  questions: array of TQuestion;

procedure TForm1.BStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  j: integer;
  line: string;
  arrayLength: integer;
  question: TQuestion;
  stringList: TStringList;
begin
  stringList := TStringList.create;
  stringList.LoadFromFile('questions.txt');

  for i := 0 to stringList.Count - 1 do ;
  begin
    line := stringList[i];
    if (length(line) >= 2) then
      if (line[2] = ' ') and ((line[1] = '-') or (line[1] = '+')) then
      begin
        arrayLength := length(question.answers);
        SetLength(question.answers, arrayLength + 1);
        question.answers[arrayLength] :=
          Copy(line, 2, Length(line) - 1);

        if zeile[1] = '+' then
          question.correct := arrayLength;
      end
      else
      begin
        question := TQuestion.Create;
        question.title := line;

        arrayLength := length(questions);
        setLength(questions, arrayLength + 1);
        questions[arrayLength] := question;
      end;
  end;
  BStart.Visible := False;
end;
```

Comment: I see it was answered, but next time, test what happens if you turn on all range  and overflow checking.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort will try that next time. I'm not used to such an ancient programming language that can't even warn me about an extra semicolon.

Comment: Logic errors will never be found. And the most recent FPC is from this year.

Comment: But this particular one should is a mistake in almost all cases, because the for statement is a noop.

Comment: @Clashsoft: ancient indeed, since Pascal predates C. FreePascal is however far from ancient,and logic errors are yours, so don't blame the language. Exactly the same error can happen in other languages too and you won't get a warning either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my Pascal knowledge goes to 10 to 15 years ago. However, I can see that you have an extra semicolon at the end of this line:

```
for i := 0 to stringList.Count - 1 do ;
```

Comment: I realized this after I posted the question... thanks anyway. I guess the segfault comes from accessing the uninitialized variable `i`.

Comment: No, it comes from accessing the stringlist with an `i` that is beyond the borders.

Comment: Ok, check the link below:

http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/rtl/classes/tstrings.html

It shows the super-class of the stringlist. There are many public things you can apply.